# Horizontal and Vertical filtering in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a question regarding double filtering in R table.
My data is like:

```
   A | B | C | D
1  10| 11| 12| 13
2  14| 15| 16| 17
3  18| 19| 20| 21
4  22| 23| 24| 25
```

And I try to get one numeric result out of it with shiny dropdowns for column name and row names.
for example: Column "C", Row "3" = 20.

At the moment I'm filtering by column and then by row, but as a result a get the vector with the whole row.

```
By_Row <- Dataset %>% filter(Row == input$RowCodeSelect)
By_Column <- By_Row %>% select(input$ColumnCodeSelect) 
paste(By_Column)
```

I hope there is a better way to make it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Dataset[input$RowCodeSelect, input$ColumnCodeSelect]`

Comment: "Error: invalid subscript type 'builtin' ". Any specific package is needed for that?

Comment: No package needed, it is base R. `Dataset[3, "C"]` is 20, please check the value of `input$RowCodeSelect` and `input$ColumnCodeSelect`

Comment: Thanks, it actually helped, but after the indexing rowname and columnname to numbers.

Comment: It should work with strings. Glad it helps, i can post an answer if I solved your issue.